# ORDER BY with two columns is much slower than ORDER BY on either column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
create table image_tags (
    image_tag_id serial primary key,
    image_id int not null
);

create index on image_tags(image_id);
```

When I execute a query with two columns, it is ridiculously slow (eg, `select * from image_tags order by image_id desc, image_tag_id desc limit 10;`). If I drop one of those columns in the sort (doesn't matter which), it is super fast.

I used `explain` on both queries, but it didn't help me understand why two columns in the `order by` clause were so slow, it just showed me how much slower using two columns was.

Comment: It's best to show the `EXPLAIN` output; it might not have told you much, but that doesn't mean it won't tell someone else something important. If you want to avoid cluttering the question use links to http://explain.depesz.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `order by image_id desc, image_tag_id desc` sorting to be optimized via indexes you need to have this index:

```
create index image_tags_id_tag on image_tags(image_id, image_tag_id);
```

Only having a composite index (with little exceptions I presume, but not in this case) would help optimizer to use it to determine the order straight away.

Answer (score 2):

```
create index on image_tags(image_id, image_tag_id);
```

try indexing..

Answer (score 1):

You only have an index for one of the columns associated with the query you want to execute, for a better speed you should create a two column index such as

```
create index on image_tags(image_id, image_tag_id);
```